# How can i add another background image to another html file via the same css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a new background image on my second html page via css, but I can't because the background image is added with the same css file and if I change it in the css it will change the background for the first page too.

What do I need to add, either on the css side or the second html side, to make the background change only on the second side?

```css
header {
  background-image: url(../wa.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="../logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="smth.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You need to differentiate the pages and apply that differential in the CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by adding a class to the header on the second html page, and specifying a different background image just for a header with that class.

```css
header {
  background-image: url(../wa.jpg);
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

header.second-page {
  background-image: url(../different-image.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header class="second-page">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="../logo.png">
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li class=""><a href="smth.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Assignments</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Info</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add Class at header like, class="homepage" in homepage header tag , class="aboutpage" in about page header tag

**home page**

```
<header class="homepage">
...
</header>

css part will be like below

header.homepage{
background-image:url('...');
}
```

**About page**

```
<header class="aboutpage">
...
</header>

css part will be like below

header.aboutpage{
background-image:url('...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it just added different tags for the 2 bodies in the 2 html files

```
  #page1 header{
    background-image: url(../wa.jpg);
    height:100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
#page2 header{
    background-image: url(../secp.jpg);
    height:100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center; 
}
```

html

Comment: Why repeat all of the identical CSS? You could simply override the `background-image`